# How to set quality of resized jpg

Tags: c1-cms

I'd like set size and quality of JPG file. I found in [doc](http://docs.composite.net/Configuration/Resizing-Images) a "q" parameter. OK, I write the parameter

```
<img src="~/media(28bd31b4-7102-461f-9206-a27d89b6be68)?mh=800&q=80" alt="blah" />
```

When I try to save it I get message *Not well-formed - '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 10, position 70.*

How can I save it?

Note 1: Default quality should be 80, as written in [doc](http://docs.composite.net/Configuration/Resizing-Images); value *imageQuality* in *Composite.config* is 80. But quality is really much lower (20?).

Note 2: Composite C1 4.2 Update 1, Build no. 4.2.5287.17495 (but upgraded from 3.x -> 4.1 -> 4.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Composite C1 is well formatted XHTML, you need to do

```
<img src="~/media(28bd31b4-7102-461f-9206-a27d89b6be68)?mh=800&amp;q=80" alt="blah" />
```

Comment: Oops, `&amp;`, off course. To my _note 1_: The default quality is really 80, but I compared it with Photoshop, which gives another results for this value; it is not relevant. So it's O.K., thanks.